# How to center active menu on horizontal navigation

Tags: jquery, css, menu

My plan is to create a looping horizontal menu on a single page website but I cannot manage to do it. Is there any way to center active menu on horizontal navigation? Please refer attached image for explanation.

[image]

Pic 1 will be the look of the navigation, and when user click number 2, the number 2 will become active and the location will be on center of the menu.

Please advise.

Comment: You don't want an advice. You want us to do your job... Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried several time and it won't work. That's why didn't come out with the code.

Comment: Plus Im still in learning jQuery and still not master it like you guys. That's why I need help here.

Comment: If you could show us something of what you have tried, we would encourage you to help...

Comment: Even if it is only HTML, you should give us something to work on, to teach you how to do what you need. Using some service like JSFiddle.

Comment: ok, Ill try again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134950/discussion-between-faliqaiman-and-tomloprod).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<ul>
        <li>menu 01</li>
        <li>menu 02</li>
        <li class="active">menu 03</li>
        <li>menu 04</li>
        <li>menu 05</li>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
    body{
    text-align: center;
}*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul{
    margin-top: 50px;
}
li{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    list-style: none;
}
li.active{
    color: red;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var nextActiveElement;
    var currentActiveElement = $("li.active").text();
    $("li").click(function (){
        nextActiveElement = $(this).text();
        $(this).text(currentActiveElement);
        currentActiveElement = nextActiveElement;
        $("li.active").text(nextActiveElement);
    });
});
```

Comment: don't forget to include jquery

Comment: yes, tested! [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dnhch4k1/), and can it slide when the item been selected? like lavalamp menu, it will highlight when hover. but for this, when user click, the menu will slide according to the position like slider.

Comment: can it be like a menu slider?

Comment: I Hope it will be possible, But it will take time.